# Remove text from textbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to clear the textbox when I press the on the image. I've made a code the changes remove the class: imgChecked. and add imgUnChecked so when I have the class ImgUnChecked I would like to remove all written text in the text box.

**That's how the HTML looks like:**

```
<li class=" multiPicLi multiPicHorizontal  item i5  none-item-exclusive  center-elements ">
    <label class="answeroption" for="v_2000x1" title="(me other...),,,,,,REQUEST">
        <span id="imgCont_v_2000" class="image-wrapper fluid imageBox imageBox_162134 imgChecked">

        </span>
        <span class="labeltext nobox">(me other...)
            <i class="h">,,,,,,REQUEST</i>
        </span>
        <span class="text defaultWidth" style="">
            <input name="v_2000" id="v_2000x1" class="text pictxt imgMultitTxt valid" maxlength="255" title="(me other...),,,,,,REQUEST" type="text" value="" data-for="mccimg_v_2000" onclick="return false;">
            <span class="accessibility">(me other...)
                <i class="h">,,,,,,REQUEST</i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
```

**And Here's the how my JS Code looks like:**

```
    else if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('item-exclusive')
        && $(this).hasClass('imgChecked')){
         console.log('4');       

        $(this).addClass('imgUnChecked').removeClass('imgChecked');

        if($(this).hasClass('imgUnChecked')){
            $('#v_2000x1').val('');
            console.log("text should be deleted now");
        }
```

Any Help will be much approciated!

Comment: Why do you have `text` in `$('#v_2000x1 text').val('');` ? should it not be  `$('#v_2000x1').val('');`

Comment: I've tried that code already and it's still not working! it does print the console but it doesn't empty the textbox

Comment: Can you please provide us with a jsfiddle? There might be some issue in other code of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to remove the text from the input box which id should be `v_2000x1` and has class `text` also. You have change your code like below.

```
 if($(this).hasClass('imgUnChecked')){
    $('#v_2000x1.text').val('');
    console.log("text should be deleted now");
 }
```

Comment: I've tried that code already and it's still not working! it does print the console but it doesn't empty the textbox

Comment: May be you have the same id many places. is it so? can you share the full HTML and javascript?